# How to export unusually formatted text file into panda data frame

Tags: python-3.x, file-read

I need to combine a lot of text datafiles into one Excel spreadsheet.
each file I am trying to read that looks like this:
[... if open in Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VeLg.png)

[... if open in Word Document with formating symbols shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVJUI.png)

If I simply use pd.read_csv() I've got an error "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 42 fields in line 13, saw 46"
SO I used this code to try and get the data into panda dataframe:

```
s = pd.read_fwf('data\Summary013019.txt',skiprows = 1)

sm = s[s.columns[:17]].copy()


print('dims',s.shape)
new_index = range(sm.shape[0])
sm.reindex(new_index).head()
sm.dropna(inplace = True)
sm.drop(['Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 4',
'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8',
'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 11', 'Unnamed: 12',
'Unnamed: 14', 'Unnamed: 15'],axis = 1, inplace = True)


sm.columns = ['number','sample','areaEt','area_nprop','ratio','conc']
ssm = sm.iloc[1:-2,:]
ssm.set_index('number', inplace = True)
```

When I open it, the dataframe looks fine, however, there is a problem with number format, so I cannot continue and combine files in Excel for further calculations.
    `ssm.info()`
gives me this:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Index: 88 entries,    1   to   88

    Data columns (total 5 columns):
    sample        88 non-null object
    areaEt        88 non-null object
    area_nprop    88 non-null object
    ratio         88 non-null object
    conc          88 non-null object
    dtypes: object(5)
    memory usage: 4.1+ KB`

How do I get the right (int or float) formats for my columns?
I tried other ways to convert text file into panda dataframe, I tried to use dtype attribute in pd.read_fwf() - nothing works. Or, may be I need to use completely different approach to export the text file? Really appreciate any help.

Comment: I have no experience with pandas, so I don't know if it can parse that input file directly. But since it's all fixed-width it should be easy to create a normal csv file from it, either by writing a small Python script or by using a spreadsheet program (In Excel - DATA -> Text to Columns (select Fixed width))

Comment: I tried to parse directly to pandas  csv - did not work. I know I can do it in Excel. But the idea is to treat a LOT of csv files  -  need to automate it with python. My problem is not so much to parse it  but it gets the wrong format and I cannot work with non-numerical values when I have them all combined as tabs in a big Excel file.